# two-way data-binding for edit-text, and LiveData ViewModel Class

Tags: android, android-databinding, mutablelivedata

I have a question about two-way data binidng implemented by MutableLiveData in ViewModel Class for and EditText.

If I define a LoginViewModel Class for a user, which is consisted of User, email and password as follows:

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val user = MutableLiveData<User>()
}
```

and

```
data class User(var email: String, var password: String)
```

when I rotate the phone (configuration changes occurs), the data entered will be gone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.udacity.shoestore.screens.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/fragment_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fragment_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fragment_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".screens.login.LoginFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_text"
            style="@style/title_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:text="@string/str_email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="@string/str_email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="@={loginViewModel.user.email}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            style="@style/title_style"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:text="@string/str_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_edit" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="@string/str_password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="@={loginViewModel.user.password}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:text="@string/str_sign_up"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_edit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:text="@string/str_sign_in"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_edit"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sign_up_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_edit"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.524" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I wonder if there is something wrong about defining the User data class or using it in ViewModel or something else, but it doesn't work.

On the other hand, if I define the elemnts of user seperately in ViewModel, it works:

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

and of course some changes in xml:

```
 android:text="@={loginViewModel.email}"
```

and

```
 android:text="@={loginViewModel.password}"
```

any idea?

[My ShoeStore project in GitHub](https://github.com/parissakalaee/ShoeStore)

Comment: In your first approach, `email` and `password` are regular `String`s. I don't see why changing those would cause a new value to be emitted on `user`.

Comment: @Michael Do you mean I should change like this? 

```data class User(var email: MutableLiveData<String>, var password: MutableLiveData<String>)```

I did it and it made no changes. I thougt when the User class itself is MutableLiveData, it could be emitted for its properties' changes.

Comment: If you want to emit a new value on `user`, then you must set a new value on `user`. For example, you could have `email` and `password` as `MutableLiveData` members of the ViewModel, with two-way data binding, and make `user` a `MediatorLiveData` with `email` and `password` as its sources.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your comment, I didn't get why I need that, but I changed the line to : ```    val user = MediatorLiveData<User>()
``` and nothing happened. I still lose the data entered for email and password, when I rotate the phone (configuration changes)

Comment: If that's the only thing that you did then it won't solve anything. A `MediatorLiveData` emits data based on changes in other `LiveData`s, and you have to explictly add those other `LiveData`s as sources for the `MediatorLiveData`.

Comment: Actually I changed three files, User.kt (to define MutableLiveData for email and password), the related xml file and the LoginViewModel as follows: 
```class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val user = MediatorLiveData<User>()
//    val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
//    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()
}```

you may check the project on GitHub, I added the resource link.

Answer (score 0):

I use this exact same implementation in my app.

Did you set binding lifecycleOwner in your activity or fragment ?

Comment: I set this in LoginFragment.kt:  ```binding.lifecycleOwner = this```

Comment: and your answer is interesting to me, because I have another data class in my whole project that lifecycleOwner is the activity and there is no problem related to losing data during configuration changes. But there I set the lifeCycleOwner to Activity, because the viewModel is shared between two fragment, and it is not the case in LoginFragment. Is that the solution? Why can't I set the lifeCycleOwner to Fragment, and view model class memebers as live data in two-way databinding?

Comment: I always use binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner in fragments. Using this is discouraged in fragments, it may be the cause of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

When using viewmodels, this is actually how I do it.

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User> get() = _user
}
```

In my fragment onCreateView

```
override
fun onCreateView(...){
   val binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(...)

   binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
   binding.viewModel = viewModel

   ...
}
```

I'll check your project on GitHub and let you know if anything...
Sorry for the late reply. I was busy playing with Jetpack Compose ;)

Comment: Don't mind the implementation in this viewmodel because it usually applies to only data that is consumed by the UI. i.e one way databinding

Comment: thanks for your comment, I changed the lifeCycleOwner to what you said, but nothing happened. what is your User data class? it is really a big help, if you can check the code in Github